# Is there a way to detect if changes from a branch has been indirectly merged with another?

Tags: mercurial

Let's say we have three named branches A, B and C. Is there a (non ocular) way to detect that changes from C has made it into A?

```
A ----------------------------
  | \              /
B |  \------------/
  |           /
C  \---------/ -------
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with Mercurial 1.6.0, you can use revsets to find this:

```
hg log -r "ancestors(A) and branch(C)"
```

This shows all the ancestors of A that are on the C branch.  You can use templating to extract exactly the information you need from the log entries.

See `hg help revsets` for full details.